# Call function inside another function

Tags: matlab

I have a function

```
function toto(a,b)

    [out,~] = evalc(a)
    % here I would like to call another function 

    myFunc(x,y,file);        
end
```

How could I pass this function as args to toto function as sometimes I want to call `toto(a,b)` and some other times `toto(a,b,@()myFunc(x,y)` ?

Comment: Usually I agree with the votes on questions, but I can't see why this question got a -1... Anyone care to explain?

Comment: @RobertP.: I can only guess that someone saw the `evalc` that doesn't relate to the question and was blinded by rage.

Answer (score 2):

(*Answer before question edit: assumes fixed number of inputs to `toto`*)

If you want to call an arbitrary function from within function `toto`: first define a handle to that function:

```
f = @myFunc;
```

and then pass that handle as input argument to `toto`, so that you can use it within `toto`:

```
function toto(a,b,f)

   [out,~] = evalc(a)

   f(x,y,file); %// call function whose handle is f        

end
```

Comment: +1! You copy pasted my answer before I posted it... Or so i seems at least... Should mention nargin though, as OP specifies that he wants to call the function with different number of inputs...

Comment: @RobertP. Thanks! My telepathic powers, you know... :-D

Comment: is it ok with this modif ?

Answer (score 1):

Define your function with an input to pass a function handle:

```
function toto(a,b,fun)
...
% You must know how many inputs and outputs to expect
% but nargin and nargout do work for function handles
% so you can handle different cases if needed.
[y1,y2,...] = fun(x1,x2,...);
...
```

Call the function and pass in a handle to the function:

```
toto(a,b,@FunName)
```

Or:

```
FunHandle = @FunName;
toto(a,b,FunHandle)
```

You can pass in additional parameters by using an anonymous function:

```
Param = 'FileName';
AnonFunHandle = @(x1,x2)FunName(x1,x2,Param);
toto(a,b,AnonFunHandle)
```

Comment: I'm showing you (and the many other people in this community) how to do this in general, not how to solve this one problem. If your function does't return any outputs then don't put any outputs! That simple. "Teach a man how fish" as they say.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to use both the `toto(a,b)` and `toto(a,b,f)` or similar function calls, you need to use `varargin` and `nargin` (and their output counterparts).  Here is a very basic example; it ignores any more than two outputs or any more than three inputs, and does not do any input checking etc.

```
function [vargout] = toto(a,b,varargin)

if nargin >2
    func = vargin{1};
    fout = func(a,b);
else
    fout = []  % if no third argument is given returns empty
end

if nargout > 0
    varargout{1} = a+b;
end

if nargout > 1
    varargout{2} = fout;
end

end
```

So for example you can call this as `x = toto(2,3)` (returns x = 5), `[x y] = toto(2,3)` (returns x = 5, y = []), `[x y] = toto(2,3,@(x,y)(x*y))` (returns x = 5, y = 6).